# Why can't a JSONObject be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json, multithreading

```
  JSONObject quotesObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
                Log.e("leb","4");
                //get it as array
                JSONArray projects = quotesObject.getJSONArray("project");
```

I have got the Json from my server.
And these is my error info:

```
12-19 11:56:17.314: W/System.err(456): org.json.JSONException: Value {"category":"1","Body":"eeee","Price":"110.0","ID":"1","NowPrice":"10.0","idRef":"1","user":"1","Title":"I"} at project of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

12-19 11:56:17.374: W/System.err(456):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
12-19 11:56:17.374: W/System.err(456):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
12-19 11:56:17.413: W/System.err(456):  at com.supinfo.sup.rest.ProjectRestDao$RestTaskGetAll.doInBackground(ProjectRestDao.java:197)
12-19 11:56:17.434: W/System.err(456):  at com.supinfo.sup.rest.ProjectRestDao$RestTaskGetAll.doInBackground(ProjectRestDao.java:1)
12-19 11:56:17.434: W/System.err(456):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-19 11:56:17.434: W/System.err(456):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-19 11:56:17.434: W/System.err(456):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-19 11:56:17.434: W/System.err(456):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-19 11:56:17.434: W/System.err(456):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-19 11:56:17.434: W/System.err(456):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: because the json shown here is not an array.

Comment: This JSON represents a json object not a JSON Array!

Comment: There is no JSON array in your server response.

Comment: Show your whole json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your response your do not have any kind of `JSONArray`. It only contains `JSONObject`. So you have to parse it as below :

simply create an `JSONObject` from given string and then extract all values from jsonObject as :

```
//create json object form responce string
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(responseStr);

//get nickname
 String category= object.getString("category");
 String body=object.getString("Body");
///.... get other value for object
```

and also use [JSONObject.has(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) for checking is current json object contain mapping for given name or not

Answer (score 0):

Both are developed for different purpose and to solve the different problems, as object you can have multiple values stored in single object, and for JSONArray you can save multiple objects and traverse them.

If you are getting problem due to conversion reason then there is problem in the parsing logic. analyze the JSON output properly and then parse it.